# c# error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a window with a datagrid and a chart. The data grid has 5 rows of data and the chart graphs the data of the row based on the selected row. Right now it only graphs the first row and doesn't update the graph when I select a different row. This code is in a class called ShellViewModel.cs:

```
public void EditLoadForecastViewModel()
{
    Shell sh;
    Timer timer = new Timer(500);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
        if (updateGraph)
        {
            sh.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateLoadChart()), null);
            updateGraph = false;
        }
    });
    timer.Start()
}
```

This function is called in a window called Shell.xaml like this

```
private void btnResults_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vm.ReadLoadForecastFile(false,false);
    vm.EditLoadForecastViewModel();
}
```

When the button is pressed i get an error pointing at this line:

```
sh.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateLoadChart()), null);
```

The error message is

> **NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code : Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: `Shell sh` is never assigned

Comment: When you put a breakpoint at the start of `btnResults_Click` and hovered the mouse over `vm` when the debugger hit the breakpoint at runtime, what did you see? When you put a breakpoint immediately after `if (updateGraph)` and hovered the mouse over `sh`  when the debugger hit the breakpoint at runtime, what did you see?

Comment: You have to instantiate sh like `Shell sh = new Shell();`

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a new instance of the Shell object sh.

```
Shell sh = new Shell();
```